# Applicative functors within lambda expressions, non-exhaustive patterns?

Tags: haskell, lambda, applicative

I'm testing out applicative functors in lambda functions, but I'm stuck with the below code I've written. 'myAddition' need to take the cumulative total of 'Random a':

**I appreciate there are better ways to do the below, however I'm learning functors so this is relevant**

```
data Random a = Nill | Random a deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)

randomOrNot = [Nill, Random 22, Random 101, Nill, Random 44]

instance Functor Random where
  fmap f (Nill) = Nill
  fmap f (Random a) = Random (f a)

instance Applicative Random where
  pure a = Random a
  (<*>) (Random a) = fmap a

cumulativeTotal :: [Random a] -> Random a
cumulativeTotal li = foldr (\el acc -> (pure (+) <*> el) <*> acc) (Random 0) li

main = do
  print $ cumulativeTotal randomOrNot
```

The error:

```
"Non-exhaustive patterns in function <*>"
```

I understand what the error means, however I'm unsure how to make the applicative functor lambda exhaustive?

Comment: What should it do if you applied it to Nill?

Comment: You are not handling the case `(<*>) Nill` in the `Applicative Random` instance.

Comment: Your `Random` type is just `Maybe` in disguise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way you can solve this:

```
 instance Applicative Random where
     pure a = Random a
     (Random f) <*> (Random a) = Random (f a)
     _ <*> _ = Nill
```

First, bring into the format `f (a -> b) <*> f a)` and define result for first case as `Random (f a)`. Then, handle the case where your input is Nill by setting the result to Nill, regardless of the `f (a -> b)` and `f a` terms. This will address all possible values for the `Random` constructor and solve your non-exhaustive pattern problem.

Alternatively, you may choose to break the cases down further like so, with the same result:

```
instance Applicative Random where
    pure a = Random a
    (Random f) <*> (Random a) = Random (f a)
    _ <*> Nill = Nill
    Nill <*> (Random a) = Nill
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/VSZ65664)

Comment: What if I want to skip/ignore the Nill values? Otherwise, with your solution above, any instance of a Nill value results in the cumulative output being Nill.

Comment: So what would your expected output look like for the given input?

Comment: [Nill, Random 2, Random 4] = Random 6 (versus your solution which = Nill)

Comment: I am not sure that kind of skipping is possible. Based on type signature the output can only be Random x or Nill, and unless you somehow inject another term similar to f in the first case, any operation will not satisfy the type condition (output of type f b where b is not the same as a)

Comment: @barbrac As shree.pat18 says that is not possible in this way. A different approach is implementing [Alternative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative) for your type (cf. [asum](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:asum) in Data.Foldable).